# Descobrir o ID com terminação de maior valor

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma estrutura html desta forma:

```
<div id="container1">
    <p>Texto</p>
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <p>Texto</p>
</div> N vezes este bloco
<div id="containerN">
    <p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar o ultimo `id="containerN"`, separar o número que equivale ao `N` e colocar numa variável. Por exemplo, se o último for o `ID="container22"` eu quero colocar na variável `cont=22`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para simplificar você poderia ao invés de usar o ID para fazer a seleção usar CLASS e o dado desejado no ID, a estrutura ficaria assim:

```
<div id="1" class="container">
    <p>Texto</p>
</div>
<div id="2" class="container">
    <p>Texto</p>
</div> N vezes este bloco
<div id="3" class="container">
    <p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

E sua seleção ficaria assim:

```
var cont = $('.container').last().attr('id');
```

Comment: `$('.container').last()` não garante que retorne o numero maior, no caso do DOM estar misturado. (ainda assim `+1` pela ideia, que poderia também ser `data-id` em vez de ID.)

Comment: Correto @Sergio, presumi que as divs estariam em ordem, data-id também é uma boa.

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar o jQuery para selecionar todos os divs cuja ID começa com "container", depois ordená-los (caso o DOM nõ esteja já na ordem certa) e depois ir buscar o ultimo dessa array.

Se percebi bem a pergunta queres numa variável `cont` o numero que está no ID. Podes fazer algo assim:

```
var cont = $('[id^="container"]').get().map(function (div) {
    var nr = div.id.match(/(\d+)/);
    return parseInt(nr[1], 10);
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b
}).pop();

console.log(cont); // 22
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/42qj4217/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa forma (sem jQuery):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var length = divs.length;
var highest = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var id= parseInt(divs[i].id.substring(9, divs[i].id.length), 10);
    if(id > highest) {
        highest = id;
    }
}
alert(highest);
```